# Get User model in strongloop working with database

Tags: strongloop

How do I move the "User" model to the database?  I read the documentation on their official website, it's all about interacting with the User model on local?

Comment: so you want to create corresponding table in database for User model? and your database is sql-based?

Comment: yes, I can easily follow the instruction from the official documentation. It works perfectly on the local ds (in-memory), how am I be able to store the same User model on the sql database.

Comment: This question is too broad. You have to install appropriate connector for your database. After that you need to create datasource and connect your model to it. Documentation covers this very well with step by step instructions. See: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/datasources.json and 
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+a+database+schema+from+models to migrate your data.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I just need to create the datasource and change the model-config.json file and change the datasource to my database.